# How would you do this layout in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistackview

I'm relatively new to iOS programming but I'd like to build an auditor App which should look really similar to this:
[image: App should look like this]

I have a database and a data table which contains all the "questions" (Owner's Manual, Vehicle History Report, Air Conditioner etc) which belong to a specific section like Documentation, Interior. etc.

If something works OK then user clicks on the "Meets Standard" button if not then clicks on the "Needs Improvement button" and the user has to add some comment and a photo:
[image]

How can I do this in iOS? Should I use `UITableView`? Or `UIStackView`?

Or is this way more complex to develop? Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is any risk of the list of questions to exceed the visible portion of the display (factoring in the keyboard that might pop up), a table view is generally the way to go, so that you can enjoy scrolling as well as only holding the UIKit controls for the visible cells, rather than for all of the questions. You might use a stack view to layout the three buttons within the cell, but for all of these rows of questions, as table view is the more intuitive approach.

Comment: Thank you Rob! And how do I generate the rows? And also if I have custom buttons for each questions (Let's say instead of meet standards I can have OK, or Works fine, depending on the question.)
I send the data in JSON format but is it complex to generate the rows and the buttons and all the necessary UI elements?

Comment: Your `UITableViewDataSource`'s [`numberOfRowsInSection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:) specifies how many rows there are, and the OS will call your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, once for each question, in which you will instantiate the cell and configure the buttons and other UIKit controls. If you google "UITableView tutorial" or "UITableView dynamic tutorial", you'll probably find many demonstrations on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This is using a `UITableViewController`

This is a really good site in which it teaches you AutoLayout for begginers 
Click [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115444/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2-constraints)

I hope this helps you out! 
Good luck with future developments & glad to see more iOS developers coming into the scene!

Comment: No worries! Hope this helps

Comment: I asked this from Rob as well: And how do I generate the rows? And also if I have custom buttons for each questions (Let's say instead of meet standards I can have OK, or Works fine, depending on the question.) I send the data in JSON format but is it complex to generate the rows and the buttons and all the necessary UI elements?

Comment: @nethuszar Rob seemed to answer your question haha!

Comment: My apologies, kind of new around here, (just really started off) should of probably checked the guidlines